# javascript random sequence and class method

Tags: javascript

I have a task to do but I don't quite understand.Javascript needs to print random alphanumeric characters.I didn't quite understand this part:

> Script should consist of a class with at least one method which contains the logic necessary to produce the 3 output listed: upper case,small case upper 60% and small 40% User input can be considered to allow the user to choose one of the 3 outputs.

I did the random output with the loop but why classes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and give it a try. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: *"...but why classes."* Not *classes*, *class* (singular). Why? Because that's (part of) what the assignment is trying to teach/test: creating a class with at least one method.

Comment: I meant how to do it with class with 3 outputs.

Comment: You need to create a class, and inside it you can create 3 different methods, you need to have at least one. I guess the percentage is based on the input length, right?

Comment: yes right.So I need to do random letters,and then create a class and add method that can output it random?